# How can I make a script that will control all the navmesh agents?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I have a prefab that is attached to each created navmeshagent the prefab have the navmeshagent script with all the properties in the inspector. But I want also to make a global script with this properties to be able to control all the agents at the same time.

When the game is running the each AgentPrefab(Clone) I'm instantiating have the Nav Mesh Agent component and the Agent Control script. But I want to have this two component and script also on the Agents Manager to be able to control also all the agents and not only each one individual.

[image: Agent prefab clone]

And how I'm instantiating the agents :

[image: Agents]

The main goal is to be able to control each agent individual or/also to control all the agents.